# React MSAL: how to logout from all devices?

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular, msal-react

We have an application where we use [msal-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react) for login/logout.

Is there a way to log out of all devices with which a user is logged in when logging out?

Unfortunately, nothing can be found in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react) about this.

We also have a problem with login, so that the user has to log in again in a new tab (when opening different micro frontends - which all use the same login session), although the token is stored in local storage.

Hope someone can help here or provide a documentation.

Comment: Hi :) - nope. Your answer doesn't solve the problem for logging out from all signed in devices. It is just describing the normal logout process, which is already implemented.

Comment: Thanks for this question. Can confirm that the answer doesn't solve things for us either. - The question here was a bit larger in scope ("across devices" probably needs support for OpenID's "Session Management" spec) than my situation for just "across tabs" in one browser. So I asked [a related, smaller scoped question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73051848/419956) which may help others landing here too.

Answer (score -1):

When you have to logout of all devices through an application using **msal-react**, then you can surely configure the required application for signing out of all instances of logged in application as below:

> MSAL.js v2 provides a `logoutpopup` method that clears the cache in browser storage and opens a pop-up window to the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) sign-out page. After sign-out, Azure AD redirects the pop-up back to your application and MSAL.js will close the pop-up.

In this way, you can ensure that your react application has logged out of Azure Active Directory and all devices reciprocate the information that the user has logged out.

Signing out with a pop-up window:

```
 import { useMsal, AuthenticatedTemplate, UnauthenticatedTemplate } from "@azure/msal-react";

 function signOutClickHandler(instance) {
 const logoutRequest = {
    account: instance.getAccountByHomeId(homeAccountId),
    mainWindowRedirectUri: "your_app_main_window_redirect_uri",
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "your_app_logout_redirect_uri"
  }
  instance.logoutPopup(logoutRequest);
 }

// SignOutButton Component returns a button that invokes a popup logout when clicked
  function SignOutButton() {
// useMsal hook will return the PublicClientApplication instance you provided to MsalProvider
const { instance } = useMsal();

return <button onClick={() => signOutClickHandler(instance)}>Sign Out</button>
 };

  // Remember that MsalProvider must be rendered somewhere higher up in the component tree
  function App() {
   return (
    <>
        <AuthenticatedTemplate>
            <p>This will only render if a user is signed-in.</p>
            <SignOutButton />
        </AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
            <p>This will only render if a user is not signed-in.</p>
        </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
       </>
      )
    }
```

Similarly, if you refer to the method for signing out of the application using the redirect method, you will have to configure the URI to which it should redirect after sign-out by setting postLogoutRedirectUri. This URI should be registered as a redirect URI in your application registration.

For more information, kindly refer to the documentation link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=react#sign-out-with-a-pop-up-window